# Integral of a function greater than the function's minimum point

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-x+1}$.
>
> Prove that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx > \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

I came across this problem as I was dealing with basic real analysis matters. I'm interested whether there is another way of proving this inequality other than calculating the integral. From what I observed, the function's minima is located at $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$, but I don't know how to use this to my advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x) > \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ almost everywhere, then $\int_0^1 f(x) dx > \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Mean Value theorem for an integral $$ m(b-a)\le I=\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx \le M (b-a).$$ Where $M$ and $m$ are global max and min, respectively.